# return object created in function. mingw and cl difference

Tags: c++, return, mingw, cl

I have next code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Example
{
public:
    Example()
    {
        std::cout
            << "constructor: "
            << std::hex
            << this
            << std::endl;
    }

    ~Example()
    {
        std::cout
            << "destructor:  "
            << std::hex
            << this
            << std::endl;
    }

    static Example foo()
    {
        Example ex;

        std::cout
            << "foo:         "
            << std::hex
            << &ex
            << std::endl;

        return ex;
    }
};


int
main()
{
    Example ex = Example::foo();
}
```

Mingw compiled program says:

`constructor: 0x22fe4f
foo:         0x22fe4f
destructor:  0x22fe4f`

That is expected result for me programming only with `wingw` and `g++`
But when I tried to use `Microsoft cl` I got this:

`constructor: 00000000001BF750
foo:         00000000001BF750
destructor:  00000000001BF750
destructor:  00000000001BF790`

Two destructor calls? Only one constructor call? Ok, `foo` create it's own object and call `copy` constructor on `return`. But why I need to copy it when compiler can put object in `main` function stack like mingw and put `out` pointer as argument to `foo` function by itself?
Like this:

```
    // no return but `out` reference
    static void foo(Example &ex)
    {
        std::cout
            << "foo:         "
            << std::hex
            << &ex
            << std::endl;
    }
};


int
main()
{
    Example ex; // allocate memory in stack
    Example::foo(ex); // process/fill it
}
```

What's I do wrong or is there are any way to not call `copy` constructor and not writting code with `out` references?

Comment: Depending on the compiler versions involved gcc is probably doing return value optimisation. Visual c++ is using the copy or move constructor to create a second object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructors are not the only way to create an object. A `Copy Constructor` and `Move Constructor` (C++11 Onwards) can do the same.

In your case, when the `return ex` is executed, the instance created in the function is deleted and a new instance is created using `Copy Constructor`. you will get the print if you write the following code

```
Example(const Example &) {
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor" << std::hex << this << std::endl;
    }
```

The copy happens before the destruction of original object and hence you'll see this print before destructor.

Why its not happening in some compilers?

Because  of a mechanism called RVO (Return value optimization), the compiler intelligently understand that you'll be using the same instance and hence it's being moved instead of being copied.

Hope its clarifies.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I read about RVO but i still have the question. Is there are way to not cal `Copy Constructor` or force `cl` compiler to RVO or even tricks to avoid massive copying content of one object to another?

Comment: Higher optimization levels generally prevent the unnecessary copy. Try this with 02/03 level. To completely avoid it you can use move constructor which is available in C++11 onwards

Comment: yay. O1/O2 levels realy helps. ok, I'll use it for first time but looks like danger code.